# Stopping a Storyboard Animation for a specific element

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I am using the following code to start / maintain a storyboard animation:

```
private Storyboard storyboard = null;
private DoubleAnimation leftArrow = null;
private DoubleAnimation rightArrow = null;
public void AnimateArrows(bool left = true, bool right = true)
{
    if (storyboard != null) storyboard.Stop();
    else storyboard = new Storyboard();

    storyboard.Children.Clear();

    if (left)
    {
        leftArrow = new DoubleAnimation();
        leftArrow.From = 0.5;
        leftArrow.To = 1;
        leftArrow.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        leftArrow.AutoReverse = true;
        leftArrow.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(leftArrow, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(leftArrow, btnLeftAS.Name);
        storyboard.Children.Add(leftArrow);
    }
    else
    {
        storyboard.Remove(btnLeftAS);
    }

    if (right)
    {
        rightArrow = new DoubleAnimation();
        rightArrow.From = 0.5;
        rightArrow.To = 1;
        rightArrow.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
        rightArrow.AutoReverse = true;
        rightArrow.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(rightArrow, btnRightAS.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(rightArrow, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));
        storyboard.Children.Add(rightArrow);
    }
    else 
    {
        storyboard.Remove(btnRightAS);
    }

    storyboard.Begin(this, true);
}
```

I need to be able to disable the animation for an arrow / element at any given point while maintaining the other animation.

I am attempting to pause the animation for one of the arrows like so:

```
private void btnLeftAS_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    AnimateArrows(false, true);
    ((Image)sender).Opacity = 1;
}
```

However, after calling this, the animation continues. I've tried each of the options listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493(v=vs.110).aspx

What am I missing here? How do I stop the animation for one element?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you learn to use XAML when designing your UIs, rather than trying to do these things in code. What you want can be achieved without any code behind at all. This can of course be extended to suit your purposes, but try something like this:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Path Name="Arrow" Data="M10,0 20,20 11,10 11,30 9,30 9,10 0,20Z" 
                Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="FadeStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.5" To="1.0"
                                Duration="0:0:0.3" AutoReverse="True" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeStoryboard" />
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeStoryboard" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, I do actually prefer to do this part in a code behind for multiple reasons. (Learning how it works, reusing storyboard objects for other animations[might not be a valid reason, but it seems like it at first glance]). Regardless, this answer isn't really an answer to the question of stopping the animation of a specific element. (Two images are being animated using the same storyboard. They should be animating at the same rate / time.)